# Power BI REST API query parameters

Tags: powershell, powerbi-embedded

I am using the new query parameters API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt845781.aspx

I am able to call parameters fine, however when trying to set them I get an error message.  After parsing the error I get this

> VERBOSE: POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/e7229a42-46ef-4d80-b8ca-e42909509dbb/datasets/5ef116d7-917... with -1-byte payload
>
> error : @{code=InvalidRequest; message=Dataset Parameters list is invalid in 5ef116d7-9179-40a2-8a30-a657265dfe4a. Reason: Empty;
>   target=5ef116d7-9179-40a2-8a30-a657265dfe4a}

I don't understand because the parameters list is not empty? I have created a physical table with the parameters and tried and then also created a list of values in the manage parameters settings and it still gives the same error.

PowerShell -

```
$parametername = "YourData" 
$parametervalue = "Company1" 

#POST body 
$postParams = @{
"name" = "$parametername"
"newValue" = "$parametervalue"
   }
```

JSON from documentation (I am not including `updatedetails` in PowerShell because I don't know how)

```
 "updateDetails": [ 
    { 
      "name": "MaxId", 
      "newValue": "5678" 
    }, 
    { 
      "name": "StrParam", 
      "newValue": "Another Hello" 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of your PowerShell code where you set the parameters and post them?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have added the relevant parts of the code

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Get-Dataset-Parameters-from-REST-API-for-Direct-Query-Dataset/td-p/376812)

**You just need to enable the Load for the parameters**

[image]